# What means the message: WeakMap keys must be objects

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I use Vuetify for a project. On localhost, everything works well. When i run pnpm build, and upload the dist to the server, there I have the following error:
TypeError: WeakMap keys must be objects or non-registered symbols

I figured out, that this error is linked to the v-select component. If i delete the v-select component, there is no error.
does anyone have an idea what is the error?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Do you have an update on this issue? We are experiencing it as well in our production environment, it happens spontaneously. Never seen it in a development build, few time locally on a production build. We use Nuxt3 with Vuetify, Sentry gives a trace related to VOverlay.

Comment: @RiesvGeffen I figured out, that this error happens only in Safari. I have still no idea...

Comment: @Peter, it mainly happens on Safari, but we've seen it happen in Chrome twice. Does it happen consistently for you? Any chance you can make a reproduction? Cause then it would be nice to open an issue in the Vuetify repo. The setup we have it doesn't happen consistently, so it's hard (impossible so far) to create a reproduction snippet.

Answer (score 12):

try to off extensions in your browser like "dark reader", "ad-blocker" and so on. this helped in my situation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Were you able to replicate this issue consistently?